# Run script as a different user from root

Tags: root, privileges

From root user, how can I give permissions to another user to execute the file /root/script.sh ?

The idea is to run the script like `sudo -u user1 /root/script.sh`

Comment: The question is not completely clear: "your are root and want to run the script as user1" or "you are user1 and want to run the script as root"? If the first is the case, what is the problem with the `sudo` command you wrote?

Comment: Check out `su(1)`

Answer (score 12):

I must say I never liked `sudo` (especially its configurations). Plain old `su`:

```
su -c 'command' - user
```

Executed from root, it won't prompt for password.

Answer (score 0):

The user must have

1. execute permission for the whole directory path (here `/root` only)
2. execute permission for the file
3. read permission for the file

It may be a good idea to leave `/root` untouched and create (or use) a different directory for this purpose (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`). You can make `user1` the only user who is allowed to execute the script by making it the owner of the file or leave `root` as owner and group, set the simple access permissions (`chmod`) to `770` and add `user1` with ACLs (`setfacl`).

Answer (score 0):

If your script is located in the root dir, then

```
$ LC_ALL=C ls -ld /root
drwx------ 17 root root 4096 Mar  5 20:14 /root
```

`user1` can only be root.

Your `/etc/sudoers` entry will look like

```
Cmnd_Alias SCRIPT=/root/script.sh

# user who is allowed executing /root/script.sh
%user ALL = (ALL) SCRIPT
```

You normally would edit the file with `visudo`

You then also don't need to put `-u root` to your `sudo` command.

The `%` means the user group. When you leave it out then only the user is allowed to execute the command. If you want a group of users to execute it, then leave like it is.